# ASP.NET Login control focus in FireFox

Tags: asp.net

I am using the Login control. Just in FireFox, I am finding that I cannot click directly on the UserName field. I need to tab through all the other elements on that page. Just wondering if there is a work around to this issue?

```
      <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false" OnLoggedIn="LoginUser_LoggedIn">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding the following code to the Page_Load method on your login page:

```
AppLogin.Focus();
this.Form.DefaultButton = "ctl00$BodyPlaceHolder$AppLogin$LoginButton";
```

This will also cause the "login" button to be clicked when you click enter.

Note: The full "path" (ctl100$BodyPlaceHolder...) may vary slightly depending on whether or not you're using master pages, panels, etc. You can simply view the element on the page in your favorite inspector and find the rendered name for the login button.

More details can be found at my blog [here](http://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/quick-tip-setting-focusdefaults-on-the-login-control/).